# How to compare all values from previous hour to current hour using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case, window-functions

I have this table that I need to compare the values from the current hour with the previous hour for each ID.

| id | value | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3pm |
| B | 2 | 3pm |
| C | 3 | 3pm |
| A | 3 | 2pm |
| B | 2 | 2pm |
| C | 1 | 2pm |
| A | 3 | 1pm |
| B | 2 | 1pm |
| C | 2 | 1pm |

If the values from the current hour and the previous hour is different, the 'got_changes' table will have 'yes' value and 'no' if similar. If there's no previous hour data, it will just have 'yes' for 'got_changes'.

| id | value | time | got_changes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3pm | yes |
| B | 2 | 3pm | no |
| C | 3 | 3pm | yes |
| A | 3 | 2pm | no |
| B | 2 | 2pm | no |
| C | 1 | 2pm | yes |
| A | 3 | 1pm | yes |
| B | 2 | 1pm | yes |
| C | 2 | 1pm | yes |

I couldn't think of a good logic to do this. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: i've made a mistake there, it supposed to be 2. thanks for pointing out

Comment: @Asgar version 8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LAG()` window function in a `CASE` expression to check the previous `value` of each `id`:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN value = LAG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END got_changes
FROM tablename
ORDER BY time DESC, id;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bYGFWzbgYsthQFR1d1kf69/0).